# Nock fixtures: Ignore request body when matching

Tags: nock

In the Readme for nock it explains [how one can ignore the request body](https://github.com/nock/nock#protip).

I am using the fixtures feature of nock and I need to ignore the request body (at least partially). How can I do this? Can I write a regex in the `body` field of the json entries in the fixtures files?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself after some painful digging. Here is the solution:

I am trying to nock requests to the Kraken API. The request for the endpoint `/0/private/TradesHistory` is of method `POST` and sends a `body` containing a "query string like" string. For example the body will look like `ofs=50&nonce=xxx`. The `nonce` value changes with each request, so I want to ignore it to when looking for a matching nock. (The nonce can only be used once, it would make no sense for the client library to send the same value again).

So I have to add a "preprocessing" function as a config object to the call to `nockBack` like so:

```
import * as queryString from 'query-string'
import { back } from 'nock'
import * as path from 'path'

const before = (scope: any) => {
  scope.filteringRequestBody = (body: string, aRecordedBody: string) => {
    const { of: currentOffset, } = queryString.parse(`?${body}`) //Prepend a `?` so it is actually a query string.
    const { of: recordedOffset, } = queryString.parse(`?${body}`)
    if (!(currentOffset || recordedOffset)) {//This is the case where no offset is set. There is only possible recorded body in my case that matches this: The other body which has no offset. I replace the body with the recorded body to produce a match.
      return aRecordedBody
    }
    if (currentOffset === recordedOffset) {//This is the case where the sent body has the same offset as the recorded body. I replace the body with the recorded body in order to produce a match.
      return aRecordedBody
    }
    return body
  }
}

back.fixtures = `${__dirname}/nockFixtures/`

const { nockDone } = back('nocks.json',{before})
...//Run my queris
nockDone()
```

Now it works like a charm.